# Admob availability and charging

Tags: android, admob

I want to sell my apps, but it is currently not possible to sell apps on google market from some countries (including mine, Slovakia). So I decided I will try AdMob

1. I would like to know if I can earn money with AdMob from my country, is there somewhere list of "supported" countries?
2. Are there any payments for AdMob account (like activation, monthly charges for service, etc)? Should I wait with AdMob account registration before my app is released, or can I register now (even though I may not use it for few months) withoug any harm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no payments with ad mob(because they make money when you show an ad, and don't want to scare off potential advertiser)  and it is fine to regester as long before you release your app as you like. As it says here - http://www.admob.com/home/about - they support "160 countries". I could not find a list of these countries, but you could certainly try making an account to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but I put this here for anyone looking for a information on unsupported countries:

this
[list](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/4755589?hl=en)
which kind of old is all I could find, but I don't think any missing countries have been added since.

also to my knowledge, users from unsupported countries can still see and click the ads but it will **NOT** produce any revenues for you. so if you're targeting a certain region and its not listed above you might want to look for alternatives.